# Creating Circle Plot using matplotlib using amount of points from user input

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot, graph

I really am stumped and really do not have any idea where to go from anywhere beyond the sample code. I can kind of visualize what needs to happen with the points in which when the input integer divides the full 360 degrees it means that there will be "x" amount of points at the equidistant degrees unless I am on the wrong track there too. Thank you all in advance.

Here is the problem prompt:
Develop a Python program to plot a circle in a window.
First, import the matplotlib.pyplot
i. (10 Points) Ask user to enter the number of points to plot a circle. Define two lists, one to
hold the x values and another to the y values of each coordinates. The x values can be
determined by using cosine and the y values can be determined by using sine.
ii. (5 Points) Choose a style to use for the graph.
iii. (5 Points) Create two variables, fig and ax. Use.plot() function and .scatter()
function to plot your data.
iv. (5 Points) Customize the chart, giving axis names and a title. Change the font size for
each name and a title.
v. (5 Points) Assign the line width and the color more visible of your choice.
vi. (5 Points) Finally, show the graph

Here is the code I have so far/sample code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math
ky_N = input('Enter the number of segments: ')
ky_x_values = []
ky_y_values = []
ky_n = int(ky_N)
ky_angle = 360 / ky_n
#create for loop
    ky_x_values.append()
    ky_y_values.append()
```

Comment: [Matplotlib tutorials](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/index.html) can be helpful to get started. You could call something like `y_k = math.sine(k*angle*math.pi/180)` to get the k'th y coordinate.

Answer (score 0):

You can run the following code to get what you want. I have not added color commands. I believe you can find them on the internet and add to it as per your liking

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Define the Radius of a circle
R = 1
# Define the number of Edges
n =64
# Subdivide the interval (0, 2*pi) into n points
t = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, n+1)
# Take inputs from user
x = input('Enter the value of x')
y = input('Enter the value of y')
# Use cos and sin functions on x and y respectively
x = R*np.cos(t)
y = R*np.sin(t)
# Add axis and labels
plt.title('My title')
plt.xlabel('categories')
plt.ylabel('values')
# Display the circle
plt.axis("equal")
plt.grid()
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.show
```